# How To Aggregate Multiple DataFrame in a Better Way?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, merge

so I have 36 DataFrame That I Have To merge in one DataFrame on this three columns ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']

So , that's what i've done :

```
mi_pollution_1 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/DatiAirQuality/MI_Air_Quality/data/mi_pollution_10273.csv' )
mi_pollution_1.columns= ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']
mi_pollution_2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/DatiAirQuality/MI_Air_Quality/data/mi_pollution_10278.csv')
mi_pollution_2.columns= ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']
mi_pollution_3 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/DatiAirQuality/MI_Air_Quality/data/mi_pollution_10279.csv')
mi_pollution_3.columns= ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']

.
.
.
.
mi_pollution_35= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/DatiAirQuality/MI_Air_Quality/data/mi_pollution_6372.csv')
mi_pollution_35.columns= ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']
mi_pollution_36= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/DatiAirQuality/MI_Air_Quality/data/mi_pollution_6372.csv')
mi_pollution_36.columns= ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']
```

and then:

```
 frames = [mi_pollution_1 , mi_pollution_2 ,mi_pollution_3 , mi_pollution_4,
     mi_pollution_5 , mi_pollution_6,mi_pollution_7 , mi_pollution_8,
     mi_pollution_9 , mi_pollution_10,mi_pollution_11 , mi_pollution_12, 
     mi_pollution_13 , mi_pollution_14, mi_pollution_15 , mi_pollution_16,
     mi_pollution_17 , mi_pollution_18 ,mi_pollution_19 , mi_pollution_20,
     mi_pollution_21 , mi_pollution_22,mi_pollution_23 , mi_pollution_24,
     mi_pollution_25 , mi_pollution_26,mi_pollution_27 , mi_pollution_28, 
     mi_pollution_29 , mi_pollution_30, mi_pollution_31 , mi_pollution_32,
     mi_pollution_33 , mi_pollution_34, mi_pollution_35 , mi_pollution_36]

 df_result = pd.merge(frames , on = ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement'])
```

so , I wanted to know if there could be a more efficient and "cleaner" way to make it happen.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file contents are homogeneous, which look like they are based on your example above, I think it could be cleaner to load the data up as lists first.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

file_name = ['sample_file1.csv', 'sample_file2.csv', 'sample_file3.csv']

content = []
for n in file_name:
    with open(n) as f: 
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        content += list(reader)[1:] # If the first row contains headers

df = pd.DataFrame(content)
df.columns = ['Sensor ID' , 'Time Instant' , 'Measurement']
```

Comment: Thank's a lot , indeed , much cleaner and effective that the 'mess' above :-) , thank's again